# How do I use reflection to get data out of a hibernate object?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

Here is an example of an issue I am having using reflection.  This is a simple case, but what I eventually need is to dynamically build the method name on the fly... but even this simple case I can not get to work!

```
Client1 cData = (Client1) session.get(Client1.class, 1);
int cType = cData.getClientType();
int cType2 = -1;

Method method[] = null;
Method getCTypeMethod = null;

try {
  method = cData.getClass().getMethods();
  for (Method m : method){
    System.out.println(m.getName()); // displays getClientType
  }

  getCTypeMethod = cData.getClass().getMethod("getClientType", int.class);
  if (getCTypeMethod != null){
      cType2 = (int) getCTypeMethod.invoke(cData,  int.class);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}        
assertEquals(cType,  cType2);
```

The line:

```
getCTypeMethod = cData.getClass().getMethod("getClientType", int.class);
```

Always throws an exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Client1.getClientType(int)

Comment: It will be great if you provide the code for `Client1` class.

Comment: The method [getMethod](http://goo.gl/uL0Dxk) receives the param classes, not the return type, your `getClientType` receive a `int`? if not, try `cData.getClass().getMethod("getClientType");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [getMethod](http://goo.gl/uL0Dxk) receives the param classes, not the return type, your `getClientType` receive a int?

If not, try:

```
cData.getClass().getMethod("getClientType");
```